# Install a Bootloader to Boot Another Partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, grub, bootloader, kubuntu

I currently have an external hard drive that is partitioned to 3 parts:

- dev/sdb1 - Files
- dev/sdb2 - Kubuntu 11.10
- dev/sdb3 - linux-swap

I'm using GRUB on my built-in HDD in order to boot dev/sdb2. I might bring this external hard drive with me when I'm traveling. Is it possible for me to install a bootloader onto this drive to boot Kubuntu 11.10 so I don't have to carry my computer with me? If so, how? I appreciate any suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot up your Kubuntu, and install grub in it (in /dev/sdb). Then go to /etc/fstab and edit the file so that all sdb's are sda.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain what you mean by "all sdb's are sda"? And also, my OS is not on the first partition, and that's the main problem because my BIOS complains "Missing Operating System" when I select my external HDD on boot.

Comment: I've heard that I can't do this because the BIOS checks the first sector of the HDD for this and my OS is on the second partition of the drive.

Comment: when you open the file /etc/fstab you'll see 'sdb' in multiple places. Change that to 'sda'. If you install GRUB on /dev/sdb (not on /dev/sdb1, etc.) then you should not see the missing OS error.

Comment: ok, i'll try that tomorrow. please keep in mind my actual os is on the second partition, and the first partition of my HDD is only for storage. i'll be installing grub on the second partition and i'll change the fstab too. thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, Baha, but when I opened the fstab file, I couldn't find any "sdb"s anywhere. Here's the link to my fstab file: (francis-fac.zapto.org/fstab). Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: so you need to change sdd's to sda's. but why would you install grub on the second partition? it doesn't matter where your system is installed. try installing grub to the MBR, which is /dev/sdb (or /dev/sdd in your case).

Comment: I already installed GRUB onto /dev/sdb. I don't know where "/dev/sdd" came from, since there are only 2 drives on my computer. I will change sdd to sda and see what happens then. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about GRUB, but I couldn't find any other UUIDs for any other drive. In the fstab file I showed you, you can see that all paths are UUIDs, and basically that's it. There are no /dev/sdb or /dev/sdd parts to edit, since they're comments. Should I just proceed with a reboot? Again, I'm sorry, this is my first time with Kubuntu.

Comment: Never mind, I got it! Thank you soooooo much!!! I rebooted the computer with GRUB installed to /dev/sdb, and it works! Thank you!

Comment: glad it works. sorry i didn't pay attention to the comments.